# login into adword without use api

Tags: python, urllib, google-ads-api

There is a way to login into adwords without use api, in order to parsing it to get informations about: campaings, keywords clicks and so on...

something like:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin'
data = [('Email', 'foo@gmail.com'), ('Passwd', 'secret'),
        ('accountType', 'GOOGLE'), ('service', 'adwords')]
urllib.urlopen(url, urllib.urlencode(data))

startpage = urllib.urlopen('https://adwords.google.com.br/select/snapshot').readlines()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the API?

Comment: The short answer is yes, but save yourself the hassle and don't. You'd just be creating another API, except with layers of leaky abstraction introduced by the Adwords' UI that will make it a nightmare to maintain. Someone else has done the hard work for you already, why do you want to reinvent the wheel when you're not even using as good tools as the first guy?

Comment: Each AdWords API operation performed consumes a certain number of API units, that's why I don't want to use adwords API  Costs are charged at a rate of US$0.25

Answer (score 2):

I am a GUI test automation programmer, and som my experience is highly relevant to this question. I create tests designed to interact with a system, as a user would, at the request of my employer, who develop the software I am trying to test. This is an extremely complicated process even if you have to hand the entire source code and implementation documentation - in fact it's a full time job, and it's how I make my living.

So bearing tis in mind, you *can* do this, but *please* save yourself the hassle and don't. You'd just be creating another API, except with layers of leaky abstraction introduced by the Adwords' UI that will make it a nightmare to maintain. Someone else has done the hard work for you already, why do you want to reinvent the wheel when you're not even using as good tools as the first guy?

You say that:

> Each AdWords API operation performed consumes a certain number of API
>   units, that's why I don't want to use adwords API

Paying $0.25 per 1000 units will be cheaper to maintain that your custom API will be to develop AND maintain, and you don't even have the resources to hand which I would working in my day job; Not to mention the fact that I imagine there will be some sort of bot-detection on the adwords website.

Do you feel like writing a Captcha decoder?

Just optimise your code to use as few units as possible, have one less coffee every week, and put your feet up instead of battling against google like this.

Or if you must, make it open source so others can learn from it...

Comment: Each AdWords API operation performed consumes a certain number of API units, that's why I don't want to use adwords API

Comment: paying $0.25 per 1000 units will be cheaper to maintain that your custom API will be to develop AND maintain. Not to mention the fact that I imagine there will be some sort of bot-detection on the adwords website. Do you feel like writing a Captcha decoder? Just optimise your code to use as few units as possible, have one less coffee every week, and put your feet up instead of battling against google like this. Or if you must, make it open source so others can learn from it...